# CMFCTabCtrl's Active tab close button

Tags: mfc-feature-pack

In CMFCTabCtrl there is a function EnableActiveTabCloseButton() to have or not close button on any active tab.

I don't want to have close button only in my first tab. Th e other tab will have close button.

How to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered in this link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a6fe3ec1-0b8c-49f5-b499-84044226f1d8/cmfctabctrls-active-tab-close-button?forum=vcgeneral#a6fe3ec1-0b8c-49f5-b499-84044226f1d8

with these comments "maybe you can put EnableActiveTabCloseButton in OnActivate of the tab Control. Then you decide if it's the "first" tab, you don't EnableActiveTabCloseButton, if the active is not the "first" tab, then set EnableActiveTabCloseButton.".

This suggestion resolved my problem.